# Power Query - (1) Get Column Name (2) Split Table

Tags: powerquery

how do I get the queries for the following scenarios.

**Scenario 1:**
I have a column MAX which contains the max value out of defined columns.

**Q1:** How do I get the column name for this value?

(A solution I had in the past was based on dynamic column names, which did not work.)

**Scenario 2:**
I have a table which I want to split by columns.

**Q2:** Table 1: [X],[Z],[A],[Y],[B]  Table 2: [Z],[A],[Y]

Source:

```html
Key X   A   Z   Y   B
Cat 15  5   10  5   10
Cat 25  10      15  20
Cat 5   15  5   20  25
Dog 5   25  10  5   5
Dog 5       25      15
Bird    25  15  5   5   5
```

Here is a visualisation of my questions.

[image]

Many Thanks,
Aykut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find the max of hard coded columns  A/Z/Y then add an index and use code

```
#"Add Max"=Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index" ,"Max",each List.Max( Record.ToList( Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Index" ,{"A","Z","Y"}){[Index]}) )),
```

If you already have a maximum column named **Max** and you want to find what column it comes from within hard-coded column names X/A/Z/Y/B then use code

```
#"Add Label"=Table.AddColumn(#"PriorStepName","MaxLabel",each {"X","A","Z","Y","B"}{List.PositionOf(Record.ToList( Table.SelectColumns(#"PriorStepName",{"X","A","Z","Y","B"}){[Index]}),[Max])})
```

doing both:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table14"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Key", type text}, {"X", Int64.Type}, {"A", Int64.Type}, {"Z", Int64.Type}, {"Y", Int64.Type}, {"B", Int64.Type}}),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1),
#"Add Max"=Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index" ,"Max",each List.Max( Record.ToList( Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Index" ,{"A","Z","Y"}){[Index]}) )),
#"Add Label"=Table.AddColumn(#"Add Max","MaxLabel",each {"X","A","Z","Y","B"}{List.PositionOf(Record.ToList( Table.SelectColumns(#"Add Max",{"X","A","Z","Y","B"}){[Index]}),[Max])})
in #"Add Label"
```

If you want to select columns **col1**,**col2**,**col3**,  with those names hardcoded, then just use

```
 #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"priorstepname",{"col1", "col2", "col2"})
```

so specifically

Table1=Table.SelectColumns(#"priorstepname",{"X", "A", "Z","Y","B"}),
Table2=Table.SelectColumns(#"priorstepname",{"A", "Z","Y"}),

Comment: Hi horseyride, your proposal works as usual on my given example here.
When I apply the adapted code on my real case 30Ts rows, 60 columns, 
whereas MAX() calculates out of 5 columns, it is extremely slow.
So even in query editor I am done and can see all data, now when I want to load data back to excel it is very slow just to extract 3600 rows with 60 columns.

Is there a way of improving the code?

I read something about Table.buffer. Would this work?
Do I need to apply only 1x when I open the excel file or do I need to use Table.buffer(table) on every line with output is a table? :-(

Comment: do you really need the name of the column with the maximum in it? Otherwise it should be much simpler and probably faster to do  #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each List.Max({[X],[A],[Z],[Y],[B]}))   Not sure if a Table.Buffer around #"Added Index" and #"Add Max" would help

Comment: You are right, the code line where the column name of MAX is calculated is the performance killer !  I think Power Query need a inbuilt function like XLOOKUP.
This might solve the performance issue :-)